# How to implement OpenID in Java

Tags: java, openid

How would I go about supporting OpenID authentication in an Java web application?

Comment: my comment is this is a general question

Comment: No need to make a question like this Community Wiki

Comment: What servlet-dodathingy are you using? What web-framework are you using (if any) and so on? If you can add those to your question, you'll get a lot more (useful) answers

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376561/openid-java

Answer (score 9):

[openid4java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [openid4java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [joid](http://code.google.com/p/joid/) also.
More details at : http://code.google.com/p/joid/wiki/Introduction