# Best OpenID library for Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, openid

I want users to be able to log into my website with OpenID, but I don't know which library to use.  I know which ones are [out there](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/#java), but I would like to know which one would be best.  I'm running JOnAS, but no web framework (no Spring, Struts, GWT, etc.).  (Please don't chastise me for not using a web framework.  I have my reasons.)  For what it's worth, my web site is broken into multiple WARs, and I would prefer something that works well in that situation, but that's not a big deal.

Does anyone have experience with the different libraries?  Any experiences or wisdom you can share?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenID Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376561/openid-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have a look at http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/ and http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/wiki/QuickStart

Comment: I guess since no one else wants to answer, you win.

Comment: The latest version seems to have bug in DiscoveryInformation class. We call associate method to get the DiscoveryInformation object and store it into session when do auth request and later get in back in auth response with DiscoveryInformation dci = (DiscoveryInformation) session.getAttribute("discovered") and Tomat reponses "org.openid4java.discover.DiscoveryInformation can't cast to org.openid4java.discover.DiscoveryInformation". I guess there's some bug in class definition on constructors.

Answer (score 1):

you can see this tutorial [OpenID for Java Web applications, Part 1: Enable your Java Web applications to use OpenID authentication](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/j-openid/index.html?ca=drs)

Comment: It also uses Openid4java, only the code's getting more compilcated due to the author wraps Openid4java calls with Apache Wicket.