# Best Java OpenID library

Tags: java, openid

I know the question is subjective, but since the [OpenID libraries page](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/#java) lists a number of libraries, I thought some attempts might be made to nominate one or two that are best, in terms of:

- project activity
- quality (few bugs, easy API, properly implementing the protocol)
- documentation

I'd appreciate an answer from anyone having used any OpenID Java library

Comment: What!?! I can't just guess? :)

Comment: No, it has to be justified ;) I already have my favourite (I'm about to use it), but let's see more opinions ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best OpenID library for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956992/best-openid-library-for-java)

Comment: oh.. missed that one in the suggestions (it's at the bottom). Anyway, I insist on weighing some factors, rather than just listing (I linked the list)

Comment: My choice would be [openid4java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/). See also [OpenID Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376561/openid-java).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My choice was openid4java, because:

- it is in a public maven repository
- it's been actively developed (see the activity indicator on google code)
- it worked fine, with the documentation provided
- it's easy to use